# Angular routing 404 for js extension files (asp.net core IIS detailed error exposing physical directory)

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, web-config

I have an SPA (Angular) setup inside Startup.cs file of my Asp.net Core application which is hosted on IIS. In my application, there is a custom 404 error page for incorrect urls.

When navigated to incorrect urls like - https://myapplication.com/assets/js/mordernizer.min & https://myapplication.com/assets/js, i get a custorm error page.

But a route with a .js extension - https://myapplication.com/assets/js/mordernizer.min.js(this file doesn't exist) gives me 404 Not found IIS detailed error. This exposes the physical directory of my server which is the problem.

[image]

Is there a way in Angular I can handle the routes with requests to js extension files? My IIS  configuration - httperrors errormode= custom is not working as well. Any solutions?

Comment: I'm 100% sure it is not related to Angular. The server handles the response and shows these erorrs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved! I just had to set httpErrors configuration in web.config file at Angular level (dist folder). All this time I was modifying the Asp.net Core application web.config file. Anyway thanks!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30344945)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly". Only local request can see detailed error message and remote requests see custom error page.

For example:

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" responseMode="File" path="404.html" />
    </httpErrors>
```

[image]

[image]